# Ошибка Code 409 pyTelegramBotAPI

Tags: python, telebot

Вкратце, пытаюсь задеплоить *ТГ* бота на *Render*. 
При запуске файла с кодом самого бота вылазит ошибка:

> telebot.apihelper.ApiTelegramException: 
> A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. 
> Error code: 409. Description: Conflict: terminated by other getUpdates request; make sure that only one bot instance is running.

Я знаю, что оно выводится если бот запущен на двух разных устройствах, но самое интересное, что если я запускаю код на своем *IDE*, то все нормально, а если я пытаюсь его задеплоить на хостинг, то вылазит всегда эта ошибка.
Помогите пожалуйста.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]